# Facebook sends empty POST to a webhook

Tags: facebook, webhooks

I am trying to install a webhook for leadgen event for my page via a facebook app. So I have:

1. Facebook Page where leads come from
2. Facebook App
3. Webserver where I want to save leads

App and webserver are connected well I believe. Webhook is shown at app page etc. But when I am trying to create a test lead with this tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lead-ads-testing I am getting a POST request with no data in it.

I was suspecting permissions problems, but I am able to check a lead from page (via leadgen_id) directly with PHP SDK and the POST request is sent from Facebook just by URL, so they don't know about tokens yet.

**UPD** Plain POST request to the same url (`curl -d "param=value" https://..url..`) works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook sends the leads data in the request body. If you are using a framework, please check if you have access to the request body.
Try using a third party intermediate service like Runscope to see the full request, it is very usef

Comment: Okay, I see what are you talking about. It's being sent as a serialized string, not as a set of parameters. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Facebook sends webhook data as `Content-Type: application/json`, not as `…: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (as a normal form with method=post would.)

Therefor, PHP does not populate $_POST – you need to read the raw input stream instead. That can be done using `file_get_contents('php://input')` – and then just apply `json_decode` on that data, and you’ll have a proper data structure to work with.

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me...

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['hub_mode']) && $_REQUEST['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe' && $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'] == "<mytoken>") {
    echo $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
} else {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    file_put_contents('logFB.txt', print_r($data, true));
}
```

First part is for verifying webhook, second for getting data from facebook webhook.

Hope this will help...

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using the django framework, you should request.body, as post data will remain empty.

```
def webhook_response(request):
   # it will print the contents from facebook webhook response
   print(request.body)

   # something like the following object will print up if you are using leadgen
   {"object": "page", "entry": [{"id": "0", "time": 111111111, "changes": [{"field": "leadgen", "value": {"ad_id": "444444444", "form_id": "444444444444", "leadgen_id": "444444444444", "created_time": 11111111, "page_id": "444444444444", "adgroup_id": "44444444444"}}]}]}
```